# EF core custom Conventions and proxies

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I create a custom IEntityTypeAddedConvention in ef-core 2.1 and enable LazyLoadingProxies by calling UseLazyLoadingProxies method.
My custom convention is a class to add composite key to model as below:

```
public class CompositeKeyConvetion : IEntityTypeAddedConvention
{
    public InternalEntityTypeBuilder Apply(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
    {
        Check.NotNull(entityTypeBuilder, nameof(entityTypeBuilder));

        if (entityTypeBuilder.Metadata.HasClrType())
        {
            var pks = entityTypeBuilder
                .Metadata
                .ClrType
                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(CompositeKeyAttribute), false))
                .ToList();

            if (pks.Count > 0)
            {
                entityTypeBuilder.PrimaryKey(pks, ConfigurationSource.Convention);
            }
        }

        return entityTypeBuilder;
    }
}
```

All things work perfectly but sometimes i get a error:

> A key cannot be configured on 'PermitPublicationProxy' because it is a
>   derived type.  The key must be configured on the root type
>   'PermitPublication'.  If you did not intend for 'PermitPublication' to
>   be included in the model, ensure that it is not included in a DbSet
>   property on your context, referenced in a configuration call to
>   ModelBuilder, or referenced from a navigation property on a type that
>   is included in the model.
>   If LazyLoadingProxy disabled error not shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message indicates, the PK cannot be configured for a derived type (which could be from entity inheritance strategy mapping, and apparently now also a proxy type, although the later could be a bug).

Which in EF Core terms (and also the source code of the EF Core internal  [KeyAttributeConvention](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/dev/src/EFCore/Metadata/Conventions/Internal/KeyAttributeConvention.cs#L32)) means applicable criteria like `EntityType.BaseType == null`.

So all you need is to modify the `if` criteria as follows:

```
if (entityTypeBuilder.Metadata.HasClrType() && entityTypeBuilder.Metadata.BaseType == null)
```